# Return possible permutations for given array

Tags: python, control-flow

For a given list with string digits, I want to return the different string numbers that can be generated using all the elements in the list (so if there are 5 elements, the number should consist of 5 digits).

The task is to return the possible permutations, the smallest permutation and the maximum permutation in a list.

- answer should be converted to integers
- If '0' is present in the input, it will produce string numbers with leading zeroes, this is not taken into account when they are converted to integers.

*This is my code now:*

```
from itertools import permutations

def proc_arr(arr):


    lst = [] # define new list
    list_of_tuples = list(permutations(arr, len(arr))) # now they are tuples in a list

    # convert to integers in list
    separator = [map(str,x) for x in list_of_tuples]
    together = [int(''.join(s)) for s in separator]

    # append to new list and return the len of possible combinations, min and max value
    lst.append(len(together))
    lst.append(min(together))
    lst.append(max(together))

    #print(lst)
    return lst


proc_arr(['1','2','2','3','2','3'])
```

However, I don't understand why I do don't get the right amount of permutations.

> > input: proc_arr(['1', '2', '2', '3', '2', '3']) output: [60, 122233, 332221]

and I get [720, 122233, 332221]

another example of input & output

> > input: proc_arr(['1','2','3','0','5','1','1','3']) output: [3360, 1112335, 53321110]

Comment: If you get the right answer for a list w/o any repeating digits, then your problem is you are counting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be counting the same permutation multiple times because you re treating digits that appear multiple times as distinct.  That is, for example, `122233` and `122233` are each counted because one has the "first" 3 first, and the second does not.

One solution would be to compute how many duplicates you will have and eliminate them from your count.  In your example, there are 3 `2`s, so there are 1*2*3=6 ways they can be arranged whilst leaving everything else the same; thus, your answer is 6 times too big due to the 2's.  Similarly for the 2 `3`s: 1*2=2 ways, so divide your answer by 2.  This gets you to 720/6/2 = 60, the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I solved it using lst.append(len(set(together))) and it works. However, apparently my algorithm isn't very efficient since it takes a long time to run

Comment: You don't need to actually compute the list.